# signalr stops working in ie10

Tags: json, signalr

I am trying to learn signalR and i have a little test working.  It works in IE 9 and chrome but when i try to run it on ie10, i get t

> Please ensure json2.js is referenced before the SignalR.js file if you need to support clients without

in searching on this error it points to ie browsers before ie 8.  hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.  I have tried adding a json2.js file before the signalr and the error is still coming up.

thanks
shannon

Here is the complete error as requested.

> SCRIPT5022: SignalR: No JSON parser found. Please ensure json2.js is referenced before the SignalR.js file if you need to support clients without native JSON parsing support, e.g. IE<8.

what you suggested seems to have fixed my problem.  Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

to your HTML page to force IE to be standards compliant. Also, can you post the full error.