# SignalR browser compatibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I've created an MVC 4.0 site Based on SignalR JS Client 1.1.3 package, that I've tested on Chrome an Safari. Now that I moved to IE10 (which should fully work) I don't see any SignalR activity, same goes for Android browser. In fiddler I can see negotiate activity going on on Chrome, but when I open the same page in IE10 I get nothing.

my js conatin:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>   
<script>    
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            monitor.server.init($('#server_id').text());
        });
</script>
```

Comment: It turned to be:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818648/signalr-stops-working-in-ie10/15819443#15819443

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SignalR 1.1.3 why does your javascript point to version 1.1.2?

Comment: Actually, I didn't download the package myself - but when I came to upgrade to 1.1.3 it said I already installed 1.1.3 - So I figured 1.1.3 package had 1.1.2 files in it.

Comment: Does this mean that 1.1.2 is not supported by IE